# Is there a way to connect PDF document and Excel sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I want to know whether there is a way to connect a Fillable PDF document and excel sheet. I know this question may be little open ended. But I have been searching a lot to find out if there is a way to do it, without much success. My requirement is I want to connect a Fillable PDF with an excel sheet, so that whenever we fill the PDF document, the excel sheet automatically populates.

I am not sure whether this is possible or not. If it is possible, can anybody tell me a way to do that? So that I can search on it and figure it out?

Comment: if you have Acrobat you can create javascript inside the PDF that will fill an Excel file, say at the press of a button. Alternatively, you can program VBA in Excel to grab the data from the form via a button push from the Excel file with the Acrobat Type Library Reference.

Comment: @ Scott Holtzman That was a good head start. I would search something on this. By chance, do you have any sample codes or links regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

In the olden days, it was possible to set up a direct connection, using ODBC (and the ADBC object in the PDF). This has, however, been abandoned a few Acrobat versions ago.

The most direct connection would be based on SOAP, but it requires Acrobat; it does not work with Reader.

All other ways of communicating with a database/spreadsheet are asynchronous, meaning that you have to initiate the process from your form.

You can use the form to create a tab-delimited file which you then can import into your back end, or you can submit data to a server which then communicates with the back end. Or, as it has already been stated, you can control Acrobat using VB (or Applescript), and get data out by this way.